# fill new Columns with Open price at certain times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hoping someone can help me here... I'm absolutely lost!

Here is my dataframe: a 1 minute export of the DAX fom Metatrader5. I am wanting to add 2 new columns. "Hourly Open" and "Market Open".

```
                         Open        High        Low         Close     Vol
Date_Time                   
2022-07-04 00:01:00     12869.2     12873.5     12867.5     12869.1     63
2022-07-04 00:02:00     12868.3     12868.3     12854.9     12854.9     68
2022-07-04 00:03:00     12855.8     12861.1     12854.4     12860.8     69
2022-07-04 00:04:00     12861.1     12861.7     12854.0     12854.0     73
2022-07-04 00:05:00     12854.1     12857.3     12849.8     12849.9     58
```

1. for the Hourly Open column I would like to find the Open price at the start of each hour. I would then like to ffill() that value into subsequent columns until a new hour opens at a new price....
2. for the market Open column I would like to find the open price for a specific time: ie 08:00.  Once again Id like to ffill() that until the next day at 08:00 provides a new value....

I'm not understanding why I am having so much trouble with Pandas etc It just seems like every attempt I make at this is incorrect, plus I just haven't got the experience in Pandas to know where I'm going wrong. Every tutorial I do is helpful to a point but I'm not sure what exactly I'm seaching for....

if someone could please help me with some pointers I'd be grateful...

=============================

Thanks for the question. Hopefully this clarifies things...

1. Good Point - I'll have to drop the entries before the 08:00 time.
2. Here is what I'd like to end up with... Saved as an image

[image: final dataframe]

Hopefully that makes sense....I need to be able to refer to both the Hourly oopen and the Session / Market Open later...

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can only do it on ideal data. Namely, on the opening date (9:30 for me, you apparently have it at 8:00, this will need to be corrected) there should be a candle, if it is not there, then there will be empty values. The same applies to the hour, if there is no candle, for example, exactly at 13:00, then there will also be gaps in the nan value. **Perhaps someone will tell you how to set a range in offset in order to take the nearest available data, the same applies to the hourly frequency.**

Now for the code: the column Date_Time is converted to datetime format and made into an index. Next, a column is created with a frequency per hour Hourly Open. Then, a series is additionally created with a frequency per day, with the start time of the day at 9:30. And with this data, the Hourly Open column is filled in and the Market Open is filled in. At the end, the empty data is filled with past values.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)#these lines are needed to display all rows and columns
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)#you can remove them or comment them out

df = pd.read_csv('dax.csv', sep=',', header=0)
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'], errors='raise')
df = df.set_index('Date_Time')

df['Hourly Open'] = df['Close'].resample("H").asfreq()
df1 = df['Close'].resample('1D', offset='9h30min').asfreq().dropna()
df.loc[df1.index, 'Market Open'] = df1.values
df.loc[df1.index, 'Hourly Open'] = df1.values
df[['Hourly Open', 'Market Open']] = df[['Hourly Open', 'Market Open']].fillna(method="ffill")

print(df[['Close', 'Hourly Open', 'Market Open']])
```

Again, this will only work if the data frequency is uniform.